# CausalImpact for a single individual time series of physiological data

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, causalimpact

I am using CausalImpact for the first time and I am not completely sure whether it would be statistically correct for my case. We wanted to test if the change of enclosure did significantly impact the daily heart rate (HR) and heart rate variability (HRV) for one specific animal?

Settings:

1. Study Subject: One male
2. Data: Daily heart rate average (HR) and hart rate variability (HRV) obtained from an implantable heart monitor.
3. Treatment: Moving from one enclosure (housed with a female and 4 offspring) to another enclosure (singly housed)
4. Pre-treatment: 16 days pre change of enclosure (including the day of change)
5. Post-treatment: 15 days after the change of enclosure.
6. Results and Plot from CausalImpact: Moving to a new enclosure decreased HR by 12% (CI: -15%, -9%; p = 0.001) and increased HRV by 13% (CI: 6%, 20%; p = 0.002).

[image]

QUESTION: Is it possible to estimate the causal effect with sample from only one individual?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to put aside the fancy methodology of CausalImpact and Bayesian time-series models and suggest that you have a fundamental question of generalizability of your findings. What is the goal of this project? Are you trying to learn about how a population of people (all males?) respond to the intervention? Or, are you trying to learn how 1 specific male responded to 1 specific situation?

It seems reasonable that your 1 participant experienced an intervention that elicited some kind of change in their HR and HRV measures. You might consider if there are other explanations (diet, sleep, exercise, etc) and you might ultimately feel confident in saying that a likely cause of change in HR and HRV was the change in living conditions.

But, you only have 1 participant worth of data. Do you feel confident in generalizing to a population of all males based on the data of 1 male? Probably not. You just have no way of knowing if the change in living condition has an impact beyond your 1 subject until you measure more subjects.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, indeed, the question is if the intervention helped this one male in particular. It is only a case example as part of a bigger project.